# Comparison circle plot in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, comparison

Is there a way to create a comparison circle plot in python on Pandas dataframe, something similar to this https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/box/box_what_are_comparison_circles.htm

[image]

preferably using plotly, panda plot, matplotlib etc

Comment: I have been searching for this as well, to replicate JMP's very similar plot.